# I have to reverse a string and increment each character by 1, input - ABDEF output - GFECB

Tags: java

I have to reverse a string and increment each character by 1,
input - ABDEF
output - GFECB

I have tried it out but I'm not getting  how to increment the character

Comment: what have you tried, actually? and how would a 'Z' have to be incremented?

Comment: I take the ASCII value and increment it by 1

Comment: could you show your actual code, your actual in- and output?

Comment: Include your code in the question

Comment: Please update the question to show your work

Answer (score 0):

You can increment character by taking its ASCII values

```
String input="hello";
int ascii=input.charAt(0);
ascii++;
char temp = (char)ascii;
```

**function to reverse a string :**

```
public String rev(String input)
    {
        String output=new String();
        for(int i=input.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
            output=output+input.charAt(i);
        return output;
    }
```

**function to increment a character by one:**

```
public String modifyString(String input)
    {
        String str ="";
        for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++)
        {
            int ascii=input.charAt(i);
            

            if(ascii==122)
            {
                ascii=97;
            }
            else if(ascii==90)
            {
                ascii=65;
            }
            else
            {
                ascii++;
            }
            char temp = (char) ascii;
                    
            str =str+ (char)ascii;
            
            

        }
        return str;
    }
```